# Bank holidays schema in database

Tags: .net, database

I am trying make holidays booking system with .NET and trying to calculate working days exclude holidays and bank holidays. Bank holidays and holidays should be saved in database. Any one can give nice solution how to save it in database that later it will be easy to parse it and count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have something similar that we use in one of our databases.  Our table structure is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Holiday_Calendar](
    [CloseDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [HolidayDescription] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BankHoliday] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This structure then allows you to track all of the dates that are holidays. Using the `BankHoliday` bit field lets you distinguish between the non-Bank holidays for your processing.

here is the function that I use to get the next business date - skipping weekends and holidays.  You pass in the start date and then the number of days that you want to offset:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextBusinessDate] 
(   @startDate      SmallDateTime,
    @offsetDays     int
)
RETURNS SmallDateTime 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @nextBusDay     SmallDateTime       
    DECLARE @weekDay        int                 
    DECLARE @direction      int                 
    DECLARE @dayLoop        int                 

    SET @nextBusDay = Convert(smalldatetime, Convert(varchar(10), @startDate, 101)) 
    SET @direction  = @offsetDays/ABS(@offsetDays)  -- 1=Younger, -1=Older
    SET @dayLoop    = 0                         --

    WHILE @dayLoop < ABS(@offsetDays)               -- 
    BEGIN
        SET @nextBusDay = DateAdd(d,@direction,@nextBusDay)                     -- First, get the raw next day
        SET @weekDay    =((@@dateFirst + DatePart(dw, @nextBusDay)-2) % 7) + 1  --

        WHILE (@weekDay = 6 OR  -- Saturday
               @weekDay = 7)    -- Sunday
        BEGIN
            SET @nextBusDay = DateAdd(d,@direction,@nextBusDay)
            SET @weekDay    =((@@dateFirst + DatePart(dw,@nextBusDay)-2) % 7) + 1
        END

        SELECT @nextBusDay = dbo.GetNextBusinessDate(@nextBusDay,@direction)

        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  CloseDate
                        FROM  dbo.Holiday_Calendar
                       WHERE  CloseDate = @nextBusDay
                     )
        -- NEXT DAY
        SET @dayLoop = @dayLoop + 1         -- Always use +1 as it is compaired to absolute value of the number of days
    END 

    RETURN @nextBusDay
END
```

So if I were to run the following today (3/5/12):

```
select dbo.GetNextBusinessDate(getdate(),  -3)
```

the result would be `2012-02-29 00:00:00`

If I want a future date use:

```
select dbo.GetNextBusinessDate(getdate(),  7)
```

and the result is `2012-03-14 00:00:00`

Comment: do you want only business days, skipping weekends?

Comment: skipping weekends and holidays.

Comment: @user418319 I updated my answer with my function that I use to get the next business date.

Answer (score 0):

This book http://www.apress.com/9781430242000 has a recipe for "finding arbitrary dates"... essentially it creates a calendar table for every day, for the desired timespan (I made one that goes from 2000 to 2052; that's about 18K rows).  Then it's got columns like "IsWeekend" or "IsWeekday".  You can adapt it to add columns like "IsBankHoliday" or even "IsBankHolidayUk" or "IsBankHolidayUsa" etc.